# Iterate & Print over each Method/Attribute of an object

Tags: python, object, properties, beautifulsoup

I'm sure this is something simple but can't get to work. I want to iterate over all the attr and methods of a defined variable. However I keep one of 3 errors:

- `None` (returned several times)
- `... has no attribute 'b'`
- `[]` (returned several times)

Using BeautifulSoup object but used a `dir(string)` below as example. Getting an error either way.

```
start = "Hello"
for b in dir(start):
    print b # can successfully get list of all attr & methods

for b in dir(start):
    print start.b # should print-out command one @ a time iterating over each..not working
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `start[b]` and see if it works

Comment: @bethanyP unfortunately that did not work.